# Order of Execution for T type and non T Type method with similar Name?

Tags: c#, generics, boxing, overload-resolution

I have below methonds :-

```
protected T compare<T>(T val1, T val2)
        {
            return val1;
        }
protected bool compare(int val1, int val2)
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Now when I call Compare(10,20), we get true as output. Why does it call non T type method?

One more question I have is when we initialize a variable :-
Object 0=10; 
Here boxing occurs but why does boxing occur here since Value types are inherited from reference types?

Comment: Because the method with types is more specific?

Comment: If you have two questions then ask them in two separate questions. You have one question about overload resolution and another about boxing. Don't try to piggyback an unrelated question on another one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does it call non T type method?

Overload resolution takes the best match. Converting 10 and 20 to `int` is clearly better (since there's no conversion at all) then going with a generic type.

> why does boxing occur here since Value types are inherited from reference types

A variable of a value types on it's own is stored as a value on the stack. If you want to store it as a variable of a reference type than it's stored on a managed heap and some memory overhead is required there. For one thing, you need a pointer to where the value is stored and there are other "memory things" (I won't go to details, it's quite complicated down there).

Answer (score 4):

Because `compare(int, int)` is considered a *better* match than `compare(T, T)`, when overload resolution kicks in.

From section 7.5.3 of the C# specification:

> If MP is a non-generic method and MQ is a generic method, then MP is better than MQ.